# Получить данные об ориентации девайса

Tags: android

Как получить данные об ориентации телефона, не меняя при этом ориентацию Лейаута? Методы типа `getOrientation()` и `getRotation()` почему-то не работают... Наверное, с сенсоров нужно снимать положение?

**Edit** Положение постоянно portrait, по дефолту выставлено, так и должно быть.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getScreenOrientation(){    
    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        return "Портретная ориентация";
    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        return "Альбомная ориентация";
    else
        return "";
}
```

Можно по ширине и высоте определить

```
String private mOrientation = "";

private boolean isLandscapeMode(Activity activity)
{
    int width =
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height =
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    boolean isLandscape = width > height;

    if(isLandscape)
        mOrientation = "Альбомная";
    else
        mOrientation = "Портретная";

    return isLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Положение постоянно Portrait, эта штука не работает =(

Comment: @Nemezis16, какая версия ОС у девайса?

Comment: 4.2.1 версия

Comment: @Nemezis16, вы имеете ввиду положение дивайса в пространстве? Когда поворот дисплея выключен, или в манифесте зафиксирована ориентация? тогда только с сенсоров.

Comment: @Nemezis16, Честно говоря, я точно не помню, но если автоповорот отключен, то второй случай не прокатит, но сенсор работает всегда, до него нужно добраться.

Comment: Да, ориентация зафиксирована. Спасибо, буду думать